# Insert Data into MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, insert, prepared-statement

I am trying to insert data into a MYSQL Database, i created the following method so that i would be generic as i am going to be needing to insert a lot of data into the Database,

The Database in on the localhost

This is the Method I Created and it is being used like this.

```
       public void QueryBuilder(string command, string table, string[] columns, object[] values)
    {
        string insertStatement = command + " INTO " + table + "(";

        foreach (string column in columns)
        {
            insertStatement = insertStatement + column + ",";
        }

        insertStatement = insertStatement.Remove(insertStatement.Length - 1) + ") VALUES (";

        int countParam = 1;
        string[] paramList = new string[values.Length];

        foreach (object val in values)
        {
            string paramName = "@param" + countParam;
            paramList[countParam - 1] = paramName;
            countParam++;
            insertStatement = insertStatement + paramName + ",";
        }

        insertStatement = insertStatement.Remove(insertStatement.LastIndexOf(',')) + ")";

        MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(insertStatement, register.connection);

        for (int i = 0; i < paramList.Length; i++)
        {
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramList[i], values[i]);
        }
    }
```

This is how it is being called

```
            rg.DatabaseConnection("localhost","root"," ","login");

        rg.Open();

        object[] myobj = new object[2];

        myobj[0] = username1;
        myobj[1] = password1;


        string[] mystring = new string[2];

        mystring[0] = "username";
        mystring[1] = "password";

        QueryBuilder("INSERT","users",mystring,myobj);

        rg.Close();
```

Some hlp would be great as i dont know what is going wrong....

The Problem is that there are not syntex errors but the data is not being inserted into the database ?!!

Thanks and Regards..
:)

Comment: What's the error? What part of the code do you need help with?

Comment: You may want to execute the query after building it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, add

```
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

At the end of your QueryBuilder method (or else return the command object and then execute it if you want to preserve the function as "QueryBuilder" and not "QueryBuilderAndExecuter").